# How much energy would you need to open a portal and maintain it?

Tags: science-fiction, space, space-travel, energy, infrastructure

How much energy would you need to open a portal and maintain it? And more importantly, what would the infrastructure look like?

For example: Would a single nuclear reactor be enough, or would you need a city's worth or maybe even more? Would a single Dyson Sphere be enough? Of course, you can offer better alternatives as well.

Also, how would you transfer the energy to the portal without frying it up? What materials could the conduits and the portal need to be made out of, or is there even a material that could achieve that?

Comment: What kind of portal? Where does it lead? What does it do? How large is it?

Comment: We don't know, and we can't answer - we don't have any kind of usable portal tech, nor any promising leads towards it at the moment.

Comment: It really depends on your fantasy portal requirements. In Stargate, there's an episode (1969, season 2) where SG1 powers the gate from truck batteries. In the game Portal, you carry a hand held portal generator. So the size and power consumption of the portal generator is up to your decision.

Comment: Please remember that you are allowed *one and only one question per post.*

Answer (score 2):

**Let's answer this!**

This question falls into my "how many angels can dance on the head of a pin? Answer: As many as wanting" category. It's specifically unanswerable because there's no such thing as a portal nor anything similar we can draw on as a reference for the power requirements. Simply put, how can anybody know how much power should be used?

If you're expecting this answer to tell you how many gigawatts of power your portal needs and what gauge copper wire is required to transport all those gigawatts... well... that's not the purpose of this answer. I think you're stuck in a rut and don't realize it.

Now, I remember a small portal in the TV series *Eureka* that was powered by house current and I remember the super portals in the TV series *Stargate: SG-1* that were powered by black holes.

- The simple rule of thumb is the bigger something is the more power you need. How much, specifically? As much as you want. I'll return to this in a moment.
- The literary rule of thumb is this: the more "important" a literary [MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin) is (and that's what your portal is, a literary MacGuffin), the greater the power needed. This isn't worldbuilding so much as it's writing craftsmanship (no, it's nor storybuilding...). Human nature is to ascribe importance to something based on its impact on the surrounding environment, be it physical, psychological, philosophical, or other. In this regard, it doesn't matter if the portal is one meter in diameter or the size of a planet, if it's powered by a black hole, *it must be honking important!* That's just how we think.

**Let's return to "as much as you want"**

It's a serious temptation today to make things "as real as possible." Indeed, on this site over the last couple of years the number of "as real as possible" questions has skyrocketed. Is there anything wrong with that? Not particularly. But is there a problem anyway?

*Yes. Post authors don't know how to tell the difference between fantasy and reality.*

That's a harsh statement, but it's true. We've had people ask all kinds of wild questions about utterly fantastic (magical... unrealistic...) things with the expectation that, if they could just find the right person, someone could explain how their idea could manifest itself in the Real World.

That's not, actually, a beneficial thing to do. There's a point where you're straining at the proverbial gnat, trying to be so "as realistic as possible" that you're worrying about details that don't matter *at all* to what you're doing. Clever folks have advanced the idea that [the only way to model an infinitely complex system is with that system itself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/258709/87710). The problem with infinitely complex (or, really, any really complex) systems is that you need to be a god to describe them.

It really is a godlike undertaking to model an entire universe (or even a small village) right down to the component atoms. Thus, a line must be drawn. What you're really doing is building a *simulation,* a model of the "real universe" that can host your creative ideas. Knowing that such a line exists, we need only determine where that line should be drawn. Inevitably, new authors want that line drawn as close to "as real as possible" as they can.

Experienced authors will tell you that it's important to pick your battles. How much power does your portal require? As much as your story needs. This is called [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609) and it's just as much a part of worldbuilding as figuring out the physics of asteroid movement or any other science-based issue. Does your story need a "realistic" power quantity? Why? Even if any mathematics about portal design existed, the only people who could judge you right or wrong would be specialists in the field: and they want to suspend their disbelief as much as anyone else.

Thus, the brutal reality is that the devil really is in the details. Good worldbuilding means knowing how to cast that devil out and focus only on details that matter. Is your gate small? Maybe all it needs is a local substation and some whomping big capacitors. Is it important? Maybe it has its own super-secret dedicated nuclear power plant.

Most of the time we focus on helping people build worlds independent of stories (pure worldbuilding!) but sometimes you can't simply ignore the story. This is one of those times. You're trying to make something utterly fictional, factual. That can't be done. You can describe it in a way that's *logically factual,* meaning the reader will understand your description and derive the emotional response you hope they'll have, but that's very, very different from being scientific.

In fact, it has nothing to do with hard science at all. On the other hand, *it has everything to do with psychology.* So...

- In the world of science fiction, some (if not most) worldbuilding should be sciency. The harder your story, the more science should be involved, *all the while knowing that it's impossible to invent non-existing technologies to any meaningful degree* beyond the user interface.
- Whether or not your story adheres strictly to science should be an issue of the needs of your story, not your desires as an author. I ran a micropublisher for ten years. Of the many lessons I learned, one of them is that a perfectly good story can be ruined by too much attention to detail.
- The purest form of science fiction is that which answers the question, "what if?" Writing stories that are only 100% science-based is just writing (IMO) a boring docudrama. Yawn. Stories like the movie *Interstellar* or the TV show *The Expanse,* despite being touted as "as realistic as possible," are actually so full of scientific holes it makes one wonder they weren't writing fantasy. Those of us who can see that, however, are more than happy to suspend our disbelief because the story is just so honking good that we'll pay that price to enjoy it.

**Conclusion**

1. Make the power supply reflect the importance of your portal in the story.
2. Just describe the power cables as "power cables" and stop worrying about the material science.

If my answer was successful, I've given you useful insight into the process of worldbuilding concerning a question that doesn't have factual answers.